# XHR 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) with very simple HTTP request

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I have a very simple piece of code, to try to retrieve XML using JavaScript's xmlHttpRequest object. That's what it does right....?

If I cut and paste this URL into Firefox...

http://oracleofbacon.org/cgi-bin/xml?a=Kevin%20Bacon&b=Arnold%20Schwarzenegger&u=1&p=google-apps

...I get a valid response.

If I use the following code...

```
function bacon() {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    try{
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://oracleofbacon.org/cgi-bin/xml?a=Kevin%20Bacon&b=Arnold%20Schwarzenegger&u=1&p=google-apps",false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
    catch(err){
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

...I get an error. Can someone please tell me why?

If I save the XML returned from the URL obtained in Firefox to a local file, and use that file reference in the URL, the XML is happily loaded. Can't work out why this fails. Also returns an error in Chrome.

Regards,

Paul.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your are running into the JavaScript same origin policy.

You can only retrieve data from the same domain, your page resides on. If you want to retrieve data from a remote server, you have to use techniques like JSONP.

Comment: Many thanks, your reply is appreciated. Will try another approach.